# how to prevent insert duplication data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code that work well.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO phpc_events (cid, owner, subject, description, ctime) 
SELECT '1', '1', title, description, start_tdate from at_courses";

mysql_query($sql);
```

i put this into this page :

```
>  http://localhost/msigilearnv2/tools/calender/copy_database.php
```

when first runs the page it will copy table from at_courses to phpc_events..
when second runs.. how i can prevent duplication data? because it keep add same data. i put ignore but still not works

Comment: You should have 1 field as a Primary Key to prevent same data insertion. Primary key prevents duplication in the database. Or another alternative, you should check if the same entry exists in the database before you do the insertion. By the way please consider putting a column as a primary key in your table.

Comment: make cid be primary key or unique index, then you can prevent duplicate data

Comment: can you explain the alternative part.. i have an idea to check title and start_date before insert but not know how to do it

Comment: Does the phpc_events table have primary key?

Comment: of course.. it is eid .. not match with at_courses.. because i just insert the table from other table

Comment: @airi determine which field you want to prevent it from duplicate. Let's take cid as an example. Do a query and check number of rows returned using mysql_num_rows() where cid = '1'. If mysql_num_rows() returned more than 0, it means the record is already exist, then skip the insertion. Otherwise do the insertion. Do this logic using if else statement. Small note: consider using prepared statement or pdo as mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE isn't usually a good idea. There are errors besides duplicate keys that will prevent insertion and ignore ignores everything... It's usually better to do something like INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid=cid -- doesn't really matter which column you use for the update here. But you'll still need a unique index for it to know what it should consider a duplicate as others have mentioned.

Comment: @Chelsea yes i know what everybody talk about.. just i not know how to do it.. can you help me with this.. let say if i create a field in phpc_events that copy primary key from at_courses.. do you know how can i do if else checking for "if primary key exist after first copied in phpc_events do not copy the data again"? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing you one of the alternative. Lets say you have a record in the database and cid value is '1'.

First step check the value if it is already exists in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT cid FROM phpc_events";
$returned = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($returned) > 0){
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($returned) ){
        $PhpcArray [] = $row; //stores result returned in array to ensure less resource used
    }
}

$sqlC = "SELECT anotherId FROM at_courses";
$returnedC = mysql_query($sqlC);
if(mysql_num_rows($returnedC) > 0){
    while( $rowC = mysql_fetch_array($returnedC) ){
        if( in_array( $rowC['anotherId'], $PhpcArray ) ){
            // do nothing as id is already exists in phpc_events
        }
        else{
            // do insertion because id in at_courses is not exist yet in phpc_events
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Another alternative.

By the way you can also try this query if it matches your column as I don't know how your table structure looks like

```
SELECT cid 
FROM at_courses 
WHERE cid NOT IN (
                 SELECT cid FROM phpc_events
                 )
```

This query will return the cid in the at_courses which is not yet occur in phpc_events. Then do the insertion for those cid returned from at_courses table.

Thank you.

Comment: i think of this too but how can i check for all the table and only insert the data that is not being insert.. my problems now.. first runs it have 10 data .. second runs suppose it maintan 10 data but my sql return 20 data because of the insert statement

Comment: I am sorry but I am not getting it. Does this involves many tables? also why is your query inserting 10 rows at a time? perhaps you can post more codes in your question. maybe you query is in loop?

Comment: my code will copy data from table A to table B .. for first time the table b is empty.. next .. if table A have add some data and i runs the script i want just add the new data not whole data from table A because i have copy it before..

Comment: you can create a field as a flag in table A. Lets say if table A received 5 data, set the flag for all rows to 1. Take that 5 data and copy it to table B, and after that update the flag to 2. Whenever you run your script to copy from table A to table B, just take records which have flag = 1. hope this can give you some ideas

Comment: can you help me with this.. let say if i create a field in phpc_events  that copy primary key from at_courses.. do you know how can i do if else checking for "if primary key exist in phpc_events do not copy the data"?

Comment: sorry not really sure if I understand but I edited my codes in the answer, please take a look, hope it can give you some ideas.

Comment: now i created both table have the same primary key ...> ( course_id ) <-- auto-increment from at_couses ...  how i can prevent insertion same primary key in phpc_events because if i runs my script it will copy whole table

Comment: SELECT course_id
FROM at_courses 
WHERE course_id NOT IN (
                 SELECT course_id FROM phpc_events
                 )

see my update answer above. Using this query, it will take course_id which is not yet occurred in phpc_events. So when you want to do insertion to phpc_events, just take all course_id returned by this query

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL isn't great, but you will need to do something the like:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO phpc_events (cid, owner, subject, description, ctime) 
SELECT '1', '1', title, description, start_tdate from at_courses"
left join phpc_event on phpc_events.cid = at_courses.cid //(and others you want matched for dups
where phpc_events.cid is null
;
```

Comment: hi.. your code works after the insertion... if the data not yet created then it wont work.. only work after created

Comment: It will.  Hence the "left join".  If phpc_event.cid is null, then it is not there.

Comment: wait i check again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key in your tables, you can replace `INSERT` with `REPLACE`. This will insert new records or replace them if the primary key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

alter the table by adding UNIQUE constraint

```
ALTER TABLE phpc_events ADD CONSTRAINT your_field UNIQUE (cid, owner, subject, description, ctime)
```